# Creating line between point to nearest neighbour point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polyline-creation, nearest-neighbor

I have a layer of points in QGIS which represent electric poles.

How do I create a polyline layer that would have lines running between the poles so it can represent the the electric cables that connecting the poles together?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

In the processing toolbox there is an algorithm called ["Points to path"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path).  There you can connect points based on certain conditions (or you can leave it blank).

Comment: Yeah, but I have no idea which fields to choose to get the lines to between nearest neighbours

Comment: @tristramit I don't know how your data is structured.  If the poles are digitized in a systematic way, there can be an order in which they can be connected.  Btw, with electric poles, the proximity is not always a reason to be connected by a cable...

Comment: Your'e correct.
it's not a data that I collected, I got it and it only has fields such as phisical charecteristics and no numbering.
Anyway, I want to make to make a polyline layer which I can later on correct in the field

Comment: I still don't have an answer.
I know how to create lines between points but I don't know how to create it between nearest neighbours